# When should I force interpolation on a Gstring?

Tags: groovy, string-interpolation

I'm working on code that will scan a db table for column names, and then build a SQL statement to create table based upon a subset of columns.  The end statement can be quite huge (60 cols in some instances).

Here's a small snippet:

```
        case ["VARCHAR", "CHAR"]:
            clause = "${row.name} ${row.colType.trim()}(${row.length})"
            break
```

My question is when I should force interpolation of the GString.  Currently I wait until I build the entire statement, then call `.toString()` at the very end.  Would it make any difference if I called `.toString()` at this level instead?

More code:

```
            //CONTEXT
    def rs = inputs.connection.sqlConnection.eachRow(tableNamesSql){ row ->
                clause = buildSqlClause(row)
                columnNames.append(clause).append(',\n') 
    }
    def formatted = columnNames.toString().replaceAll(",\$", "")

    def sql = """CREATE TABLE ${inputs.outputSchemaName}.${inputs.outputTableName}_${inputs.cycle} (
            ${formatted}
            ) IN TBTS_${inputs.outputSchemaName}"""
```

And the code that analyzes the row:

```
def buildSqlClause(row){
        def clause

        switch(row.colType.trim()){
            case "INTEGER":
                clause = "${row.name} ${row.colType.trim()}"
                break
            case "DECIMAL":
                clause = "${row.name} ${row.colType.trim()}(${row.length}, ${row.scale})"
                break
            case ["VARCHAR", "CHAR"]:
                clause = "${row.name} ${row.colType.trim()}(${row.length})"
                break
            case "TIMESTMP":
                clause = "${row.name} TIMESTAMP"
                break
            case "DATE":
                clause = "${row.name} ${row.colType.trim()}"
                break
            default: throw new Exception("Invalid SQL data type: [${row.colType}]")
        }
        def nullVal = row.nulls
        if(nullVal.equalsIgnoreCase("N")){
            clause = "${clause} NOT NULL"
        }
        return clause


}
```

So in other words, in the case of a db column "foo" I need the sql clause to read 
`FOO VARCHAR(INT)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you need to call toString() at all?

Also, you might get better results `collect`ing a `List` of field definition string (as you are doing), then call `join` to stitch them all together?

Comment: The answer to `toString()` is yes.  JDBC does not understand the Gstring type so I need to coerce it to a `String`.  As for using `join` I'm using a java `StringBuilder` to build the final SQL statement.  What will `join` buy me that I'm not getting?  (Don't quite catch your drift...)

Comment: It's just one less place to get it wrong...  Can you post a bit more of your code?  It's hard to give advice on a whole function based on 3 lines of code

Comment: Of course!  It's the GString/SQL issue -- usually avoided by [using `Sql.expand`](http://groovy.codehaus.org/api/groovy/sql/Sql.html#expand%28java.lang.Object%29) -- in this situation, I would probably just call `toString()` at the point of `return clause.toString()` inside the `buildSqlClause` method